# Setting the HTML <label> 'for' attribute in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

How do you set the `for` attribute of an HTML `<label>` element in JavaScript, without using jQuery or any other library?

Answer (score 203, accepted):

Use the `htmlFor` attribute. I assume it has a slightly cryptic name because `for` is a keyword in JavaScript:

```
var label = document.createElement('label');
label.htmlFor = 'some-input-id';
```

Comment: Would it not be better to just use setAttribute?

Comment: @DmitriFarkov, I don't think so. Why would it be better?

Comment: I'd say for consistency's sake. Personal disregard for syntactic sugar like this since it implies you are setting an actual property on the object rather than an attribute on an DOM element object. Answers my question though, better only subjectively.

Comment: DOM conceptually works with objects and properties. `htmlFor` is the correct way by setting the DOM element's property. No need to mess with attributes which is what `setAttribute` does.

Comment: Wish I could double up-vote this. I'm using Angular 2 to build a form and needed to update a label's for attribute dynamically. [for] was throwing up an error but [htmlFor] worked a treat. Thank you!